# How to invoke chrome.devtools.* api calls in regular chrome extension without opening devtools in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to build a regular chrome browser extension (**NOT** a devtool extension) that when activated on a particular page obtains a list of all the IPs from which resources are requested. I know how to obtain this list from the HAR log by calling chrome.devtools.network.getHAR() in the devtools_page, and then messaging the HAR log to a background script. However, you can only call chrome.devtools.* from within a devtools page, which exists only for the life span of an open devtools window in the browser. I don't want to have to open up devtools just to invoke this function in devtools.js. Is there a way to make a call to chrome.devtools.* e.g. from background.js without having to open up devtools in the browser?

Here's what's going on right now:

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "somePort");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg.content);
  });
});
```

,

```
// devtools.js
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(harLog) {
  var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "somePort"});
  port.postMessage({content: harLog});
});
```

,

```
//manifest.json
"devtools_page": "devtools.html",
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [there is no way to access to `chrome.devtools.*` api without opening up devtools window.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#creating)

> The `chrome.devtools.*` API modules are available **only to the pages loaded within the DevTools window.** Content scripts and other extension pages **do not have these APIs.** Thus, the APIs are available **only through the lifetime of the DevTools window.**